# Android: access fragment methods inside ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a ViewPager and I am putting some fragments on it. Fragments are of different classes, they will have different layouts and different buttons, functions, etc.

I am not sure If I am taking the correct approach for the task:

```
Fragment1 f1 = Fragment1.newInstance("FRAGMENT 1");
Fragment2 f2 = Fragment2.newInstance("FRAGMENT 2");
Fragment3 f3 = Fragment3.newInstance("FRAGMENT 3");
List<Fragment> fragmentsToPager = new Vector<Fragment>();
this.mPagerAdapter  = new MyFragmentAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragmentsToPager);
mPager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);
```

My question is now, if I want to iterate over the fragments in the list, since the fragments are from different classes Fragment1, Fragment2, Fragment3, is it possible to access the methods defined in the fragments or the widgets on each fragment?

```
for (Fragment f : fragmentsToPager){
    f.someFragmenthMethod();
    ....
}
```

Comment: yes, just cast the fragment to the class that has the right method.

Comment: @Vlad Matvienko for that I would need to do some kind of class check on the iteration, that is why I am starting to wonder if using fragments is the right approach to this task

Comment: you can make all your fragments to implement some interface, if you need same method for all fragments.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (Fragment f : fragmentsToPager){
            if (f instanceof Fragment1) {
                ((Fragment1) f).someFragmenth1Method();
            }else if(f instanceof Fragment2) {
                ((Fragment2) f).someFragmenth2Method();
            }else if(f instanceof Fragment3) {
                ((Fragment3) f).someFragmenth3Method();
            }

        }
```

Comment: thanks, I am just worried about if it is correct/convenient using expressions like `instance of` in such situations?

Answer (score 0):

You can define an interface(like IMyFragmentProcess) and all your fragments implement this interface (IMyFragmentProcess):

```
IMyFragmentProcessf1 = Fragment1.newInstance("FRAGMENT 1");
IMyFragmentProcessf2 = Fragment2.newInstance("FRAGMENT 2");
IMyFragmentProcessf3 = Fragment3.newInstance("FRAGMENT 3");
List<IMyFragmentProcess> fragmentsToPager = new Vector<IMyFragmentProcess>();

for (IMyFragmentProcess f : fragmentsToPager){
    f.someFragmenthMethod();
    ....
}
```

Comment: `IMyFragmentProcessf1 = Fragment1.newInstance("FRAGMENT 1");` will thatl produce a error something like: incompatible types: Required Fragment1 Found IMyFragmentProcessf1???